# Help with venting an instant pot

Tags: kitchens

We have a primary range hood over the stove.

We have a different counter on which we use an instant pot frequently. It vents steam and odor. Are there general recommendations on how to vent this? Currently, it sits below a cabinet and vents onto the cabinet. The cabinets wear out over time with the steam.

I see many people seem to have it setup this way as instant pots become more common.

If a second hood cannot be placed, are there other things that can be done to improve the situation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more for [lifehacks.se] than [diy.se].

Comment: Thanks for the Lifehacks suggestion @FreeMan, will post there.

Comment: Doubt you'll get any suggestions better than the answer below, but have fun.

Comment: Actually got a completely different and great suggestion. See https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/27526/help-with-venting-an-instant-pot/27527#27527

Answer (score 4):

If you can't bring a range hood to it, then you need to take it to the rangehood or open window.

We always put it either on top of the cooking range or just next to it.  And the normal range hood vents it just fine.

If your cooking stove/range does not have a flat surface, use a wooden chopping board to make the surface level.

Comment: Another option would be to get a small fan to blow the steam away from the cabinet.  (Personally, I'd end up rigging up a computer fan with an old wall wart or something.)

Comment: Indeed, since I'm using the InstaPot I'm not using the whole stovetop, so the vent can be positioned quite nicely directly under the fan intake (and still have 2 fully accessible burners available). I prefer to use a round metal pan rather than wood since I use gas.

Comment: A small fan like a computer fan sounds like a great idea. Thank you @Huesmann

Comment: Under the range certainly seems like a good idea, but won't work for our use case unfortunately. We neither have the space nor accessibility since our range is highly used. But thanks for the suggestion, I'm sure it'd be helpful to others.